# Connecting to Database using Node & Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I’m new to node.js and just tried to follow some tutorial. But I get nothing after I sent this GET  request.

I used following code.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host:"localhost",
    password:"",
    database:"userdb",
});

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM users", (err, result) => {
        res.json(result);
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Listening on port 3001...'));
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.
 Great blocks of white space do not help readability

Comment: Handle your errors. The query could error but no way of knowning because you're ignoring `err`. I've also written a guide on how to write better MySQL code in Node if this helps: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/